# Callable Cloud Function that invokes stripe API is always returning null

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am having an issue where the result returned by my callable cloud function is not being picked up by my client app.  The cloud function is working, at least from what I can tell, but I only ever see a null result inside my app.

Inside the app, when I try to print it to the console it is blank and stops the app, says that PrintLN needs a message. I don't know of any other way to see if the app is receiving the return data.

All my logic is happening in the cloud and I am trying to get the stripe ID back into my app, so I can save it to the preferences for later use.   So the Stripe ID is the only thing I need back in the client.

Here is cloud function:

```
exports.customerSignupApp = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
    const email = data.email;
    const password = data.password;
    const firstname = data.firstname;
    const lastname = data.lastname;
    const mobile = data.mobile;

    //console.log('Console Body:', data);

    admin.auth().createUser({
        email: email,
        emailVerified: false,
        phoneNumber: mobile,
        password: password,
        displayName: firstname + ' ' + lastname,
        disabled: false
    })
        .then(async function (userRecord) {
            console.log('User record:', userRecord);

            var userObject =
            {
                first_name: firstname,
                last_name: lastname,
                mobile_number: mobile,
                email: email,
                timestamp: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
                driver_profile: { isDriverApproved: false, isDriverDisabled: false, isDriverStatusPending: false, isDriver: false, isPickupModeEnabled: false },
            }
            stripe.customers.create({
                description: 'Firebase ID: ' + userRecord.uid,
                email: userRecord.email,
                name: userRecord.displayName,
                phone: userRecord.phoneNumber

            }, async function (err, customer) {
                console.log('New Stripe ID Created', customer.id);
                try {
                    userObject["stripe_id"] = customer.id;
                    await admin.database().ref('users/' + userRecord.uid).set(userObject);
                    const msg = {
                        to: [userRecord.email],
                        from: {
                            email: 'noreply@noreply.com',
                            name: 'REDACTED'
                        },
                        // custom templates
                        templateId: 'dlkhfjdslkfjsdlkfj',
                        substitutionWrappers: ['{{', '}}'],
                        dynamic_template_data: {
                            name: userRecord.displayName
                        }
                    };
                    await sgMail.send(msg);
                    console.log('Return Data:', userObject["stripe_id"] )
                    return { stripeId: userObject["stripe_id"] };
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error.message, error);
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error creating new user:', error);
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unknown', error.message, error);
        });
});
```

Here is the function and task inside Android Studio:

```
protected void signUserUp(String email, String password, String firstname, String lastname) {
        formatE164Number("US", mMobileField.getText().toString());
        signUserUpTask(email, password, firstname, lastname, mobileNumber)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                       if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                          Exception e = task.getException();
                           if (e instanceof FirebaseFunctionsException) {
                               FirebaseFunctionsException ffe = (FirebaseFunctionsException) e;
                              FirebaseFunctionsException.Code code = ffe.getCode();
                              Object details = ffe.getDetails();
                          }
                          Log.d("Message Failer", e.toString());
                            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "An error has occured, please try again.", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                           snackbar.show();
                          return;
                    }


                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignUpActivity.this, CustomerMainNavigationActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                  }
                });
    }

    private Task<String> signUserUpTask(String email, String password, String firstname, String lastname, String phone) {
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("email", email);
        data.put("password", password);
        data.put("firstname", firstname);
        data.put("lastname", lastname);
        data.put("mobile", phone);

        return mFunctions
                .getHttpsCallable("customerSignupApp")
                .call(data)
                .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                        String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
                        //Log.d(TAG, "Result in callable callback: " + result);
                        Log.d("Result of FB", result);

//                       SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//                       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
//                       editor.putString("stripeID", result);
//                       editor.commit();

                        return result;

                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: It looks like the value that is being returned is only being returned by the callback that you give to stripe.  The top level function doesn't have any return value at all.  I'm not familiar with the stripe API and the options it provides you, but if you can just create a promise chain (possibly using [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)) instead of using a callback, and then return the entire chain out of the top level function, things will likely go better for you.

Comment: @robsiemb Do you have a specific example?  The callback from stripe is working, so stripe is not the issue, i need the call back to be from the entire function.

Comment: Stripe isn't the issue, but the fact that the return value you want is inside of a callback that you hand to stripe is an issue (I don't personally know if stripe provides a promise-style API, which is what you need here -- if they don't, use promisify).  You need that return value to be returned by either the top level function directly, or a promise that has been returned by the top level function.

Comment: Callable functions need to return a promise that resolves to the value to send to the client.  Right now, your function is not returning anything at all at the top level, which means the client will receive nothing.  It is also confusing to me that the code mixes up use of async/await and then/catch.  It looks like you're going to have to tighten up your handling of promises throughout.  I suggest taking a step back and getting something simple to work, then expanding it gradually to make progress.

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you for the suggestion.  I am a bit nee to Node JS which explains what you mentioned above. Do you have a code example, or possibly show me what my code should look like?  I have other functions that are simlar to this, so I could transfer the knowledge.  One thing to note, this identical function DOES work on IOS, meaning the data is returned to the app, so this must be something Android related.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/

Comment: @DougStevenson that link isn't very helpful, I am not sure which example I should be looking at.  I'll keep plugging away at this

Comment: I figured this out, it was, as everyone said, the return on the cloud side.  I moved the return to the outside function and now this is working.